# How to access child object's properties using ASP.NET ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reportviewer

In our project we are using MS ReportViewer to view the page for printing. The problem I face is when binding the local report with the object data source it sees the top level properties but not the child object's properties!

Is there any method to see these properties of the child object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the report viewer? This is a bug in the 2010 version of the control. The work around is to bring the properties up to the top level object.

```
 public class MyTopLevelObject {

     public int MyChildsProperty {
         get {
              return _myChild.Property;
         }
     }
 }
```

Yeah it's not the greatest :-/

Comment: yes i already do that but the objects we use are very complex and have many levels of containing other objects - is there any way to automate this process for ex. map the properties to a dictionary or hashtabel and use it as data source

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to this, its now fixed in SP1. The requirement to get it to work is to make sure ALL classes used in properties of the datasource are serializable.

more info at:

http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2011/04/reportviewer-object-datasource-nested.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've marked your class and its properties classes as [Serializable].

It has worked for me!